# Magit: How to show differences within lines

Tags: magit

I have a file, I make some changes.
Here how SmartGit shows differences.

[image: smartgit]

As you can see it shows where the difference is within the line. It changes background to red color in concrete position. And it's very good. I don't need to spend time to find differences. I immediately see where is the difference.

Now what it looks like in Magit:

[image]

As you can see Magit says that the difference was in WHOLE line. It's not showing where the difference is within the line. So I need to find where is the difference manually. I need to do this every time. It's not very comparable.
Suppose I have differences in 20 lines. I need to spend a lot of time to find what actually changed. It's not very good.

Can magit show differences at the actual column where the change is? As in SmartGit.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you want to store that in your config, like me, just add

```
(setq magit-diff-refine-hunk (quote all))
```

to your `.emacs.d/init.el`

---

This was inspired by [phils' answer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/43644/24163).

Comment: documentation: https://magit.vc/manual/magit/Diff-Options.html

Comment: I used `(after! magit (setq magit-diff-refine-hunk 'all))` in `config.el` to get it working in Doom. [Credit.](https://github.com/robcsi/dotfiles/blob/600322c74e40990309814dbaadb8b2bbbedb5e02/doom-emacs/.config/doom/config.el#L58)

Answer (score 18):

<kbd>M-x</kbd> `customize-option` <kbd>RET</kbd> `magit-diff-refine-hunk` <kbd>RET</kbd>

See also the `magit-diff-toggle-refine-hunk` command, bound to <kbd>D</kbd><kbd>t</kbd>, which you can use to set the behaviour in the current buffer.  Use <kbd>D</kbd><kbd>C-u</kbd><kbd>t</kbd> to switch on refinement for *all* hunks in the buffer; otherwise only the refinements for the currently-selected hunk are displayed at any given time (updating as you move between hunks).

To configure the appearance of the 'refined' regions of the diff, use <kbd>M-x</kbd> `customize-face` for the `diff-refine-added`, `diff-refine-changed`, and `diff-refine-removed` faces.

Answer (score 1):

For word diffs to work magit needs to be able to use the `diff` executable.

So make sure that <kbd>M-x</kbd> `ielm` <kbd>RET</kbd> `(executable-find "diff")` <kbd>RET</kbd> returns not `nil`.
If it returns `nil` add the path to the folder containing your diff executable to the `exec-path` variable with <kbd>M-x</kbd> `ielm` <kbd>RET</kbd> `(add-to-list 'exec-path "c:/Program Files/Git/usr/bin")` <kbd>RET</kbd>

Next you need to make sure that magit is actually using that `diff` executable. For that enter a magit status buffer, hit <kbd>D</kbd> and make sure that `-x Disallow external diff drivers (--no-ext-diff)` is disabled. Otherwise disable it with <kbd>-</kbd><kbd>x</kbd>, set it as default with <kbd>s</kbd> and then save the defaults with <kbd>D</kbd><kbd>w</kbd>.

After this is done you can use <kbd>D</kbd><kbd>t</kbd> to toggle the `magit-diff-refine-hunk` option for your current buffer or follow this [answer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/43644/15303) by [phils](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/users/454/phils) to make this setting more permanent.

Answer (score 0):

Try `ediff-toggle-ignore-case` or `compare-ignore-case` variable. My guess is your diff engine is ignoring case. Might also be in diff options (I'm not sure what are the settings).

Answer (score 0):

Very similar to @loki's answer:
Use `customize-variable` with `magit-diff-refine-hunk`.