# MAGIT: easier to read diffs

Tags: magit, ediff, diff

Is there a way in MAGIT to see diffs as one line instead of two with deletions and additions in one line? It would be much easier to navigate.

Comment: You might be asking for this: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/43643/magit-how-to-show-differences-within-lines

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want ediff, in the magit buffer hit `E`, choose the diff and when they're displayed then switch to vertical mode with `|`.

Comment: No what I meant, but a nice view.